# How with beyondcode/laravel-query-detector to raise custom exception?

Tags: laravel

I have installed https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-query-detector
package under laravel 9 API app and looks like it does work for API (Crud Repository returning json in controller) and I see messages like :

```
Detected N+1 Query  .
```

But I would like to raise custom exception, when

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

in .env, as such log message can be easily missed

I config file I read :

```
 *
 * Alert:
 * Displays an alert on the website
 * \BeyondCode\QueryDetector\Outputs\Alert::class
 *
 * Console:
 * Writes the N+1 queries into your browsers console log
 * \BeyondCode\QueryDetector\Outputs\Console::class
 *
 * Clockwork: (make sure you have the itsgoingd/clockwork package installed)
 * Writes the N+1 queries warnings to Clockwork log
 * \BeyondCode\QueryDetector\Outputs\Clockwork::class
 *
 * Debugbar: (make sure you have the barryvdh/laravel-debugbar package installed)
 * Writes the N+1 queries into a custom messages collector of Debugbar
 * \BeyondCode\QueryDetector\Outputs\Debugbar::class
 *
 * JSON:
 * Writes the N+1 queries into the response body of your JSON responses
 * \BeyondCode\QueryDetector\Outputs\Json::class
 *
 * Log:
 * Writes the N+1 queries into the Laravel.log file
 * \BeyondCode\QueryDetector\Outputs\Log::class
 */
'output' => [
    \BeyondCode\QueryDetector\Outputs\Alert::class,
    \BeyondCode\QueryDetector\Outputs\Log::class,
]
```

As I do not use Console or Debugbar in this API.

I added Json option into config options :

```
'output' => [
    \BeyondCode\QueryDetector\Outputs\Alert::class,
    \BeyondCode\QueryDetector\Outputs\Log::class,
    \BeyondCode\QueryDetector\Outputs\Json::class,
]
```

But after config clearing only messages in log file are found...

If there is a way to raise custom exception or something similar ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^10.34.2",
"beyondcode/laravel-query-detector": "^1.8",
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is going to take some time to dive deep into that package's source code to solve your problem.

And that is completely unnecessary. [Lazy loading prevention](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#preventing-lazy-loading) is already part of Laravel.

It could be a good idea to switch to the very same feature that is already available.